# Position absolute, как сделать ширину как у родителя

Tags: css

Добрый вечер!

Есть такой блок:

```
<ul>
      <li id="parent">
          <a href="#">test</a>
          <ul class="child">
             <li id="child-elem">test-child</li>
          </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

У блока #parent width auto, у блока .child position absolute, как сделать ширину к блока #child-elem, как у блока #parent (width inherit не помогает)?

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выставьте абсолютному элементу left и right, равные нулю: http://jsfiddle.net/5uZLh/1/.
Лишний раз напомню, что абсолютно и фиксированно позиционированные элементы выпадают из общего потока, поэтому их лучше вообще избегать.

Comment: выпадают только фиксированные, абсолютные очень удобно позиционируются относительно relative родителя.

Comment: @eicto, фиксированные тоже на месте позиционируются, если им привязки не задавать. А насчет выпадают - вы здесь перекрытие видите: http://jsfiddle.net/6LN3N/ ?

Comment: я вообще про "избегать", надо понимать что делаешь и всё :)  естественно абсолютно позиционированный элемент, ни на кого, кроме как на своих потомков не влияет, а его позиция относительна либо документа, либо предка с position: relative;  про fixed тоже, вот как вы будете выводить что-то посреди экрана, в случае прокрученной таблицы ? будете выстраивать относительный элемент, предварительно найдя с js какой нить элемент на экране, его позицию относительно окна и документа, и двигая поля, будете пытаться нарисовать его на экране ?

Comment: @eicto ты о чем вообще?

Comment: @Fike об этом.

> абсолютно и фиксированно позиционированные элементы выпадают из общего потока, поэтому их лучше вообще избегать

Многие задачи, избегая абсолютного и фиксированного позиционирования решить если не невозможно, то сложно. вот сделайте плз [вот эту задачу](/questions/297280) на css без fixed/absolute

Comment: @eicto
1) Я не верстальщик  
2) В моем комментарии есть волшебное слово "лучше", которое намекает на "если можно сделать без этого, то лучше сделать без этого"  
3) body: overflow:hidden, height:100%; div.content-wrap: height:100%; следующий за врапом div.chat: float: right; margin-top: -X;
4) Почему тебе так важно доказать, что я неправ?

Comment: 1. я тоже
 2. так-же там есть волшебное слово *вообще*
 3. content-wrap по высоте схлопнется
 4. вы даете категоричное суждение, вас могут послушать и потом превратить это в подобие "никогда не верстай таблицы", мне потом с подобными людьми приходится работать.

---

@Fike дело не в том чтобы *вам* доказать что вы не правы, а в том, чтобы доказать это тем, кто это будет читать потом. Лично вы можете делать как хотите, как в прочем и я :)

Comment: @eicto кокой я плохой

Comment: @Fike, вот [ещё пример][1], кстати, только вчера писал.
@eicto, "не верстай таблицами" -- это да... Мне как-то пытались доказать, что игровое поле 10x10 клеток надо набирать из десяти div'ов, содержащих внутри сотню span'ов, потому что "табличная вёрстка устарела".


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/297703#297747